# In Laravel how can I make a side bar when pressed goes to the page content link but still is the current page

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I want to have the same mechanism like this https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp but in laravel application
This is my code on routes/web.php

```
    Route::get('tutorial', function(){
    $tutorial = Tutorial::get();
        return view('tutorial.index')->with('tutorial', $tutorial);
    })->name('index-tutorial');
```

// Show one Tutorial by Id

```
Route::get('tutorial/{id}', function($id){
$tutorial = Tutorial::findOrFail($id);
return view('tutorial.show')->with('tutorial', $tutorial);
})->name('show-tutorial');
```

for my Blade template
tutorial/show.blade.php

```
 <div class="container">
@foreach($tutorial as $tutorial)
<h1>{{$tutorial->title}}</h1>
<p>{{$tutorial->title_description}}</p>
<p>{{$tutorial->title_lesson}}</p>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg d-flex justify-content-end mb-3" role="group">
    <form class="mx-3" action="{{route('delete-tutorial', $tutorial->id)}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <button class="btn btn-danger" name="Delete">Delete</button>
    </form>
    <form action="{{route('edit-tutorial', $tutorial->id)}}" method="GET">
        @csrf
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="Edit">Edit</button>
</form>
@endforeach
</div>
```

tutorial/index.blade.php

```
 <main class="d-flex flex-nowrap">
 <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-bg-dark" 
 style="width: 280px;">
<a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md- 
  auto text-white text-decoration-     none">
  <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="40" height="32"><use 
  xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
  <span class="fs-4 text-white">MySql Lessons</span>
</a>
<hr>
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
  @forelse($tutorial as $link)
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{route('show-tutorial', $link->id)}}" class="nav- 
  link">
      <p class="text-white bg-dark">{{$link->title}}</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  @empty
    <p class="text-white bg-dark">No available lesson</p>
  @endforelse
</ul>
 </div>
```

I been researching a lot about having this mechanism

This one is different from other questions because i don't use controllers for this

Comment: I am very confused, so what you want is this, for example, Laravel has a [documentation site](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x), when open that link you have a side bar, but you do have a "list" in the middle top of the page, and when you click any part of that list, the pages jumps to that part on the current rendered view, do you want that? If the answer is yes, that is a frontend, has nothing to do with PHP. It is a simple `<a>` tag with an `id`, read [this](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-anchor-link-to-jump-to-a-specific-part-of-a-page.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using example tamplates from Bootstrap?
Check here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/
it's quite easy actually, you just need to copy the html code from bootstrap tamplate and tweak here and there. use
@include to add your desired components, @yield for your desired content page. and use @extends and @section inside your content pages.
roughly like this.

your main blade view

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   
  </head>

  <body>
    @include('partials.adminNav')
    <div class="row">
        @include('partials.adminSideBar')
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        @yield('container')
    </div>
  </body>
  @include('partials.footer')
</html>
```

for your side bar you just need to put links for your desired page

```
<nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
      <div class="position-sticky pt-3 sidebar-sticky">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">
              <span data-feather="home" class="align-text-bottom"></span>
              //Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="//your links/route for page content">
              <span data-feather="file" class="align-text-bottom"></span>
              //links name
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="//your links/route for page content">
              <span data-feather="edit" class="align-text-bottom"></span>
              //Links name
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

in like this in your content pages

```
@extends('layouts.adminMain')

@section('container')

<main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
    <div class="py-4">
      // your content here
    </div>
</main>

@endsection
```

make use of the @include and @yield build in function. this way you'll have a consistent navbar/sidebar but can changes the content within.
Hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using route closures, I manage to convert them to a TutorialController

```
Route::resource('tutorial', TutorialController::class);
```

for the aside bar routes/web

```
view()->composer('layout.sidebar', function($view){
$tutorial = Tutorial::all();
$view->with('links', $tutorial);
});
```

layout/sidebar.blade.php

```
<main class="d-flex flex-nowrap">
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-bg-dark" 
 style="width: 280px;">
  <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto 
   text-white text-decoration-none">
    <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="40" height="32"><use 
   xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
    <span class="fs-4 text-white">MySql Lessons</span>
  </a>
  <hr>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
    @forelse($links as $link)
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="{{ route('tutorial.show', $link->id)}}" class="nav-link">
        <p class="text-white bg-dark">{{$link->title}}</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    @empty
      <p class="text-white bg-dark">No available lesson</p>
    @endforelse
  </ul>
</div>
</main>
```

in my index.blade and show.blade you can add @include('layout.sidebar')

```
@extends('layout.app')

 @section('title', "Show Tutorials")

 @section('content')


 @include('layout.sidebar')
 <div class="container">
<h1>{{$tutorial->title}}</h1>
<p>{{$tutorial->title_description}}</p>
<p>{{$tutorial->title_lesson}}</p>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg d-flex justify-content-end mb-3" 
        role="group">
    <form class="mx-3" action="{{route('tutorial.destroy', $tutorial- 
       >id)}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <button class="btn btn-danger" name="Delete">Delete</button>
    </form>
    <form action="{{route('tutorial.edit', $tutorial->id)}}" method="GET">
        @csrf
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="Edit">Edit</button>
</form>

 </div>

  @endsection
```